# How can I pass a library to a lower dependency in node?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm trying to create a library that uses the ORM Bookshelf.js (so basically a wrapper on top of Bookshelf.js if you will). Now Bookshelf.js requires you to run a driver installation to be able to connect to the correct database (such as: `npm install mysql`) in the root of your project.

My own library also requires this, since Bookshelf.js requires it, but it keeps saying `Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'` which is normal since the Bookshelf instance does not have the mysql dependency in its node_modules folder.

If I type out the structure it would look like this:

```
* New Project
** mysql
** LibThatUsesBookshelf
**** Bookshelf
```

Now Bookshelf.js probably requires this structure:

```
* New Project
** LibThatUsesBookshelf
**** mysql
**** Bookshelf
```

Is there a way that I am able to still get bookshelf working with the first structure shown?

P.S. I know the explanation might be confusing, but it is a hard problem and I got no other way of explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the client of your module pass in an instance to bookshelf:

```
// mysuperfancymodule.js
module.exports = function(bookshelf) {
    // do fancy things with the bookshelf instance
}
```

Then in your client application:

```
// some app code:
var mySuperFancyModule = require('mysuperfancymodule'); // assuming it is published to npm
var knex = require('knex')({
    // init knex...
});
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

mySuperFancyModule(bookshelf); // init my super fancy module
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I am currently doing this, but I want to avoid the extra dependency for the user to be able to use this. There are also more problems regarding plugin registrations and others that make this hard for me to keep on doing. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: This might be personal taste, but I don't see why this would be a disadvantage. It lets the user customize `knex` and `bookshelf` to their liking before using your module. This also makes the dependencies obvious for the user of your module.

Comment: Ok, after considering this solution, I will revert back to passing the bookshelf instance instead then. Thank you for your help! :) I will mark this answer as the correct one since it's the most clean one that doesn't require injecting paths into the module.paths variable.